# Submit Button won't sit 100%

Tags: html, css

Please can someone tell me what i'm missing:

My submit button, even though it's meant to sit at 100%, does not. I just can't figure it out. Here is my code and my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1hhw6skx/

HTML:

```
<div class="inforight-contact">

<form action="contact-sent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
<p>

<label class="input">
<span>Name</span>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="name"/>
</label>
</p>
                  <p>
<label class="input">
<span>Email</span>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="email" />
</label>
</p>


       <p>
<label class="input">
<span>Subject</span>
<input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" class="subject" />
</label>
 </p> 

      <p>
        <label for="fileField">Comments:</label>
        <label for="Comments"></label>
        <textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" class="comments" cols="90" rows="4"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
       <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit"> Submit </button>
      </p>
    </form>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
form {
margin-right: 28px;
}

form label
{
display: block;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

form .submit {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: 0;
background: #EA5310;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 0.50em;
padding: 0.7em 1em;
box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #fff;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

    form .submit:hover {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            background: #EA5310;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #fff;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: 0.7;
            text-align: center;
        }

form input.name,
        form input.email,
        form input.tel,
        form input.subject {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            background: #f3f4f5;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #777;
            outline: none;
        }


form textarea.comments {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            background: #f3f4f5;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.50em;
            margin: 0em 0em;
            padding: 0.7em 1em;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: lighter;
            color: #777;
            outline: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of form margin right. Remove it your submit button will become 100%; and changes in padding of textarea and input text

```
form {
    margin-right: 28px;
}
```

check Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hhw6skx/3/) here.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes, that cracked it. Thank you!!

Comment: Did you change anything other than the margin-right? I had changed that numerous times and had no luck.

Comment: Yes as in answer says. changes in padding of TextArea and Input text. left and right margin will effect also.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you edited your answer to what else you changed. Thanks again!! Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, last question, now my text has no padding. I.e. when a user fills in the form it sits against the box. The padding achieved this look. Anyway to add the padding back without sending the box sticking out again when they click it? I tried something like "form input.name:focus p" but that didn't work.

Comment: I think you need like `input:focus { }`

Comment: I have that, but it adds padding onto the end when clicked. I have updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1hhw6skx/3/

Comment: I figured it out. I just added padding-left: 3% and width: 97%

Answer (score 0):

in this you have to change this

```
form {
margin-right: 0px;
}
form input.name, form input.email, form input.tel, form input.subject,form textarea.comments
{
padding:0.7em 0;
}
```

after this got what you want try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hhw6skx/7/)

Comment: The problem with this though is that the text that the user inputs now sits against the edge of the box....

Comment: then please try this link in which i  just change the button width all are same as firstly you enter in your question try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1hhw6skx/9/

Comment: This isn't accurate though. If you scale the page the 'submit' box doesn't always line up.